# Customizing inset map in a map series in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series

I currently have a Map Series that was generated using a Polygon Grid with a "Name" attribute that defines each map series page. On some of these pages, I'd like to add an Inset map with a larger scale to show further detail on that map page. I would like that inset map frame to disappear if I navigate to a different page in the map series (one without an inset) in ArcGIS Pro. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the UI does not allow what you want, You could try coding in python and move the inset map off the page and back on when needed?

Comment: Also suggest you suggest it as an idea on the ESRI ideas website if this is somethi8ng you want and will be doing often.

Comment: If you can create the inset maps in another project (such as a Map Series), and export them to a folder as an image file, then I assume you can do this.  I did this in ArcMap with Data Driven Pages by inserting a picture and in its properties Picture tab choosing the Simple Path from DDP and then in the index layer had a field that contained the path for each image  that I wanted to go with that page.  I assume Pro can do that and perhaps more.  A quick search on dynamic images in map series comes up with a similar process but the option is simply called Dynamic.

Comment: You could create a duplicate layout in the same project.  So you have two identical layouts, one with the inset, and one without.  Then you can choose which pages are printed/exported from which layout.